# Невозможно применить к операнду типа bool и float, Microsoft visual studio, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float runSpeed = 500f; // скорость куба
    public float strafeSpeed = 500f; // скорость смещения влево, вправо
    public float jumpForce = 15f; // мощность прыжка

    protected bool strafeLeft = false;
    protected bool strafeRight = false;
    protected bool doJump = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            strafeLeft = true;
        }
        else
        {
            strafeLeft = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            strafeRight = true;
        }
        else
        {
            strafeRight = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            doJump = true;
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-runSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        
        if(strafeLeft)
        {
            rb.AddForce(-strafeLeft, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (strafeRight)
        {
            rb.AddForce(strafeRight * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (doJump)
        {
            rb.AddForce(doJump * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
        
}
```

Всем привет, юнити выдает ошибку, не могу понять почему, гугление не помогает, делал по тутору, там работаем, у меня нет, мб что то обновили и уже работает не так? Заранее большое спасибо Вам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

__________________________ Решение______________________

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float runSpeed = 50f; // скорость куба
    public float stopSpeed = 50f; // скорость торможения
    public float strafeSpeed = 50f; // скорость смещения влево, вправо
    public float jumpForce = 15f; // мощность прыжка

    protected bool up = false;
    protected bool down = false;
    protected bool strafeLeft = false;
    protected bool strafeRight = false;
    protected bool doJump = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            up = true;
        }
        else
        {
            up = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            down = true;
        }
        else
        {
            down = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            strafeLeft = true;
        }
        else
        {
            strafeLeft = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            strafeRight = true;
        }
        else
        {
            strafeRight = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            doJump = true;
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (up)
        {
            rb.AddForce(-runSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0,0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
  
        if (down)
        {
            rb.AddForce(stopSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (strafeLeft)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, -strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (strafeRight)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (doJump)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
            doJump = false;
        }
    }
        
}
```

Comment: ты бул умножаешь на флоат. Что по твоему должно выйти умножив "ложь" на цифру, например на "100.0"? Или что должно выйти когда ты пишешь "минус ложь"?

Answer (score 2):

Все понятно описано **strafeLeft/strafeRight** - имеют тип **bool**, его нельзя умножать "*" или сделать отрицательным "-"

Вероятно так:

```
 void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-runSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        
        if(strafeLeft)
        {
            rb.AddForce(-strafeSpeed , 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (strafeRight)
        {
            rb.AddForce(strafeSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (doJump)
        {
            rb.AddForce(jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Andrew, внимательнее. strafeSpeed и jumpForce   - float

Comment: Спасибо все исправил, не заметил

Comment: @АртурВалиахметов лучшее спасибо - принятый ответ. Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.